# Java applet use httprespon

Tags: java, http, post, web, applet

- This is my code.
- I use a simple way to make POST httprespon.
- Mounted on applet.
- I work correctly in Eclipse.
- But mounted in appletviewer cause shot down.
- Web page will be shot down too.
- The amount of data is too large to deal with?
- Or is there any other reasons?
- I need help Thank you

  ```
  public class we extends Applet
  {
  Button sd = new Button("11");
  Label title= new Label();
  Label prompt = new Label();
  TextField input = new TextField(8);
  Label result = new Label();

  public void init()
  {
      add(sd);
          }

  public void start() {

  }

  public void paint (Graphics g) {

  }

  public boolean action(Event e, Object o) {
      if (e.target == input) {
          match();
      } else if (e.target == sd) {
          abandon();
      }
      return true;
  }   
  private void match() {      
  }
  private void abandon() {
      String url="http://119.14.80.132/ACT_ID_355";

  HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost(url);

  List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UNCLOSE1","1"));

  try {
      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.ISO_8859_1));
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {

      e1.printStackTrace();
  }

  HttpResponse response = null;
  try {
      response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httppost);
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {

      e1.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e1) {

      e1.printStackTrace();
  }

  if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){
      try {
          String resultq=EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
      } catch (ParseException e1) {

          e1.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e1) {

          e1.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  }
  ```

  }

appletviewer

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.security.AccessControlException: acc
ess denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "119.14.80.132:80" "connect,resolve")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlConte
xt.java:366)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:
560)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:574)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSoc
ketFactory.java:127)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnect
ion(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedCli
entConnectionImpl.java:294)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(Default
RequestDirector.java:640)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultReq
uestDirector.java:479)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpCl
ient.java:906)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpCl
ient.java:805)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpCl
ient.java:784)
        at we.abandon(we.java:130)
        at we.action(we.java:49)
        at java.awt.Component.handleEvent(Component.java:6751)
        at java.awt.Component.postEvent(Component.java:5160)
        at java.awt.Component.postEvent(Component.java:5170)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4877)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:244)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:163)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:151)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An applet runs in a 'Sandbox'. It is only allowed to open a connection to the server it is downloaded from. The error you are seeing is a security violation because you are trying to connect to another server.

Comment: So how can I do that?
Added to the JAR signature custom security?
So there is no breach of security signature will direct result of shot down?

Comment: You could sign your applet, but you need a certificate (expensive) or users need to accept untrusted executable code (highly unlikely). A better way however is to connect to the originating server. Place your applet on the server (say http://119.14.80.132 ) and also only connect to that server. If you need data from another server, implement a proxy on the originating server (where the applet is served from) to retrieve the data from the other server so the applet still only has to connect to the originating server.

Comment: I've managed to mount a signature.
But the problem does not solve.

C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.7.0_09 \ bin> jarsigner-keystore nook-storepass 654321
 -keypass 654321 se.jar ok

Warning:
The signer certificate will expire within six months.

Comment: *"The signer certificate will expire within six months."* When making a certificate, there is an option to specify a 'validity period' in days.  If not specified, it defaults to something shorter than 6 months.  On a wider note:  If this is for a 'professional deployment' you really should be using a certificate authorized by a CA (certification authority).  They are very (IMO) expensive, but have advantages over the 'self-signed' type of deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Has been answered.
I feel very Stupid.
I spent a dozen hours does not want to come out.
The answer is actually just a line of text.

```
public void init()
{
System.setSecurityManager(null);
add(sd);
add(sd2);
}
```

I still can not understand WHY?????????